# Selecting Table name from database by variable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I want to select a table to show from database .. not a specific one .
I want the user to choose the table name from a combobox , without using "if" statement .
this code is not working , any help ?

```
var tblName = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
NorthwindEntities DB = new NorthwindEntities();
var Query = from Q in DB.tblName
select Q;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MSSQL Use this:

**SELECT name AS TableName FROM sys.tables**

sys.tables fetch all table name from your connected Database.